# Extracting P-Value- SIGN test- Package BSDA in R

Tags: r, list, extract, p-value

I need to extract the p-value from SIGN.test function in package [BSDA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BSDA/BSDA.pdf):

```
> library(BSDA)
> x <- c(7.8, 6.6, 6.5, 7.4, 7.3, 7., 6.4, 7.1, 6.7, 7.6, 6.8)
> t1=SIGN.test(x,md=6.5)

        One-sample Sign-Test

data:  x
s = 9, p-value = 0.02148
alternative hypothesis: true median is not equal to 6.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 6.571273 7.457455
sample estimates:
median of x 
          7
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
> t1$p.value
Error in t1$p.value : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I tried also `str(t1)` with no use.

```
> str(t1)
 num [1:3, 1:3] 0.935 0.95 0.988 6.6 6.571 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "Lower Achieved CI" "Interpolated CI" "Upper Achieved CI"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "Conf.Level" "L.E.pt" "U.E.pt"
```

Comment: What's the output of `str(t1)`?

Comment: Aaron: I added the output for `str(t1)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's unexpected looking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into the code for the function and it doesn't seem to include that in the output unless a particular criterion (`k<1`) is satisfied, where `k` is defined within the function.  That's not what the documentation says it should do.  Your options are probably either to put a modified version of the function in your own workspace; what you need to do is to replace the last two lines

```
print(rval)
return(Confidence.Intervals)
```

with just

```
 return(rval)
```

You won't get the confidence intervals you were getting, but you could probably add those to the output list if you wanted as well, with

```
rval$Confidence.Intervals <- Confidence.Intervals
return(rval)
```

It might also be worthwhile to contact the package maintainer, though it doesn't look like it's been updated since March 2012, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and one good R programmer modified the code for me to extract the p-value.

Just do this. Your problem will be solved.

**1)** Send a line just writing SIGN.test, it will show you the function, copy it, name it whatever you like, then copy the text in step 2 and substitute them to the functions final lines...

**2)**

```
print(rval)
list(rval,Confidence.Intervals)
}
}
```

**3)** Note that the last lines were

```
   print(rval)
         return(Confidence.Intervals)
    }
}
<environment: namespace:BSDA>
```

Replace them by the lines in step 2

**4)** If we name the function by my, and store the function result in res, then p value is extracted by writing this.

**Input**

```
res<-my(x,md=6.5)
```

**Output**

> res[[1]]$p.value
>       [1] 0.02148438; where x is your vector

Reference :- https://www.facebook.com/groups/rusers/10152075287578740/